# Can not Mail. php mail() showing warning

Tags: php, email, warnings, phpmailer

Warning: mail(/home/u295560656/.logs/php_mail.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u295560656/public_html/2.php on line 9
Test email sent

What is this error all about ? Previously I was able to send mails but not now on Hostinger hosting Services.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "smthing@gmail.com";
    $to = "smthing_else@gmail.com";
    $subject = "PHP Mail Test script";
    $message = "This is a test to check the PHP Mail functionality";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
    echo "Test email sent";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually You changed to Hostinger Hosting Services. But previously you used the different hosting service. 
I think you defined the path of the logs file as static value.
So Please change the path for the logs file to current hosting service.

or else turn of the warnings by using the following statement

error_reporting(0); 
Replace the 3 line with the above statement.